# Chrome Extension - set text of clicked element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create an extension that allows the user to fill an input field with pre-defined text. The user should right click on the input field, select the option and the code would have to set the text automatically.

After some searching, I understand I need to work with a content script but I can't figure out how to locate the selected input field and change the text.

## event.js

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "context_positive",
    title: "✔ Positief",
    contexts: ["all"]
});
```

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    if (tab) {
        if (info.menuItemId === "context_positive"){
            // Call content script and get it to locate the source element and set text value
        }
    }
});
```

## content_script.js

Since you click the input field, it should be accessible by using document.activeElement but during testing it usually would just select BODY as activeElement..

```
document.activeElement.innerHTML = "test";
```

So I'm unsure of how to go from the event.js action to the content_script.js section to enter text in the selected input field. Any advice on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You can get advantage of the click event:

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input");

document.querySelector(".editable").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  let element = event.target;
  if (element.innerText) {
    element.innerText = input.value;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="editable">
  <span>Example text one</span>
  <p>Example text two</p>
  <div>
    <span>Child text example one</span>
    <span>Child text example two</span>
  </div>
  <div>Example text three</div>
</div>

<br><br>
Text to replace: <input type="text">
```

Comment: The input field can be any input field on any website, so I won't have any idea of id's and class names of said fields.

The extension should be able to set the text into any given input field when right clicked on it and selecting the extension name in the menu.

Comment: @m1ch14l I mean, this is an example. I don't have the full context to code it for you.